# Customer Deleted; No backup;

Tags: orders, delete, user

My client had deleted all customer accidentally. And unfortunate we don't have any backup.

Any way to recover a customer and their history order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an external hosting provider, contact them - they might have automated backups set-up of their complete server or just the databases. So you might be able to recover the lost data.

Other than backups, there is no way to recover lost data in such cases.

Comment: `sales_flat_order` table saves customer email. So Can I manually create customer from email id and can I link those customer again to `sales_flat_order table` ?

Comment: I can't say for sure, I've never done something like that...but Magento's db structure is complex. You would need to create the new customers and then adjust their ID to match the orders. You would probably need to adjust this in several linked tables as well so definitely backup your DB and first try this on a test instance. If you are not familiar with the DB structure of Magento, you will probably have a hard time successfully doing something like this...